# How to parse this Betting API?

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

i'm not very experienced in getting Jason responses in Android. My question is how to parse JSON coming from this API `https://api.the-odds-api.com/v2/odds/?sport=UPCOMING&region=uk&apiKey=e3b70c1881a5d9eec34e4cb256844874`. Basically for introduction, i need participants of events.Then I want to create a list of matches and create  `RecyclerView` from it.

This is my class for communicating with API

```
private class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> implements OnVisibleCallback{


    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();


            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line+"\n");
                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);   //here u ll get whole response...... :-)

            }

            return buffer.toString();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        Log.d("json",response);
        try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
            String data = jObject.getString("data");
            JSONObject objData = new JSONObject(data);
            String events = objData.getString("events");
            JSONObject eventObj = new JSONObject(events);
            int numberOfEvents = eventObj.length();





            List<Match> matchList= Arrays.asList(new Match("Juventus","Fiorentina"));


            counter = 1;
            Log.d("Counter_Ticket_Fragment", String.valueOf(counter));

            mAdapter = new MatchAdapter(matchList,counter);
            changeVisible();
            mAdapter.setCallback(this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void changeVisible() {
        if(mAdapter.getItemCount()>0){
            noMatch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            noMatch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow I got to the events but don't know how to proceed with this. I need a number of events because I want to create as many objects of Match.class(String homeTeam, String awayTeam) and pass it to the recycled view. I am doing this on this JsonTask and I think that's really not the best approach.`JsonTask` is being called in  `OnCreateView` of  `Fragment`.

This is Match.class

```
   public class Match  {

private String team_home;
private String team_away;



        public Match(String team_home, String team_away){
            this.team_home = team_home;
            this.team_away = team_away;
        }

public String getHomeTeam() {
    return team_home;
}

public String getAwayTeam() {
    return team_away;
}
}
```

And this is MatchAdapter

```
   public class MatchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MatchAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private List<Match> matchList;
private Context context;
private int counter;
private static SharedPreferences prefs;
private OnVisibleCallback callback;


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView team_home, team_away;
    public View v;


    public MyViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        this.v = v;
        team_home = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.team_home);
        team_away = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.team_away);
        context = v.getContext();

    }
}


public MatchAdapter(List<Match>  matchList, int counter) {
    this.matchList = matchList;
    this.counter = counter;
}

public void setCallback(OnVisibleCallback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
public MatchAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_matches_row, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MatchAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Match match = matchList.get(position);
    holder.team_home.setText(match.getHomeTeam());
    holder.team_away.setText(match.getAwayTeam());



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return matchList.size();
}

}
```

Comment: create POJO classes for the json and use retrofit 2 for API call

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your backend json data because the data is not structured well.

Create an array of event in which every element of an array is an object then parse your data with the code below

```
       JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
        String data = jObject.getString("data");
        JSONObject objData = new JSONObject(data);
        String events = objData.getString("events");
       JSONArray jsonEvent = 
                            objData.getJsonArray(events);
       for(int i=0; i<jsonEvent.length; I++){
             JsonObject jsonObj = jsonEvent.getJsonObject(i);
       }
```

Comment: I'm not making the backend, this json is used by betting API. I agree that the json structure should be changed.I would put evens as an array. The above code does not work for me since events is string and it is unable to resolve method getJsonArray(java.lang.String)

Comment: contact the developer support for this api provider to follow the proper structure of beck-end

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
            String data = jObject.getString("data");
            JSONObject objData = new JSONObject(data);
            String events = objData.getString("events");
            JSONObject eventObj = new JSONObject(events);
            int numberOfEvents = eventObj.length();


            for(int i = 0; i<numberOfEvents; i++){
                event = eventObj.names().getString(i);
                String matchOne = eventObj.getString(event);
                JSONObject singleEventObj = new JSONObject(matchOne);
                JSONArray participants = singleEventObj.getJSONArray("participants");
                }
```

I did iterate over events names(keys) and everything works now as excpected